# how access to keys in map[interface{}] interface{}

Tags: go, yaml

this is my yaml file:

```
db:
    # table prefix
    tablePrefix: tbl

    # mysql driver configuration
    mysql:
        host: localhost
        username: root
        password: mysql

    # couchbase driver configuration
    couchbase:
        host: couchbase://localhost
```

and i use go-yaml library to unmarshall yaml file to variable:

```
config := make(map[interface{}]interface{})
yaml.Unmarshal(configFile, &config)
```

config value:

```
map[mysql:map[host:localhost username:root password:mysql]      couchbase:map[host:couchbase://localhost] tablePrefix:tbl]
```

how access to **db -> mysql -> username** value in config without predefined struct type

Comment: Please show an example. Your provided code works and wouldn't cause this error.

Comment: I update my question @jimb

Answer (score 2):

YAML uses string keys. Have you tried:

```
config := make(map[string]interface{})
```

To access nested attributes, use [type assertions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions).

```
mysql := config["mysql"].(map[string][string])
mysql["host"]
```

A common pattern is to alias a generic map type.

```
type M map[string]interface{}

config := make(M)
yaml.Unmarshal(configFile, &config)
mysql := config["mysql"].(M)
host := mysql["host"].(string)
```

Comment: i have a dynamic config file and maybe involve array value

Comment: the default type for the ""gopkg.in/yaml.v2" package is `map[interface{}]interface{}`

Comment: YAML places no restrictions on the type of keys; in particular, they are not restricted to being scalars. Example bindings to native types include Perl’s hash, Python’s dictionary and Java’s Hashtable. (https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't define the types ahead of time, you need to [assert](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) the proper type from each `interface{}` you encounter:

```
if db, ok := config["db"].(map[interface{}]interface{}); ok {
    if mysql, ok := db["mysql"].(map[interface{}]interface{}); ok {
        username := mysql["username"].(string)
        // ...
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/koSugTzyV-